# How to call function on controller through directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my directive I have a link that calls a function:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="resetFilter()">Reset Filter</a>
```

js

```
app.directive('resetFilter', function () {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'myFilter.html'
  }});
```

I have defined a resetFilter function in my controller:

```
$scope.resetFilter = function () {
    console.log('resetfilter');
}
```

The problem is that the function is not firing? how can I get it to work?

Comment: Works for me, see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QXc5VAUURbNYPLfUYIpR?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Simple Directive has controller method and since your directive has default scope. it will inherit the parent scope by default.

```
app.directive('resetFilter', function () {
return {
templateUrl: 'myFilter.html'
controller: function ($scope) {
   $scope.resetFilter(); // this will call function defined in your controller.
 }
}});
```